# Elasticsearch match on property that has multiple values (array)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index like this

```
 {
            "_index": "entities",
            "_type": "names",
            "_id": "0000230799",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "FIRST_NAME": [
                  "Deborah",
                  "Debbie"
               ],
               "LAST_NAME": "Jones"
            }
         }
```

I attempt to do a match query on the name, but unless the first name is exact, no hits return

I would expect the below query to generate at least one hit and score it, am i wrong about that?

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/entities/names/_search?pretty=true' -d '

{
 "query": { 

            "match":{
                "FIRST_NAME":"Deb"
                }
        }

}'
```

my mappings are

```
    {
   "entities": {
      "mappings": {
         "names": {
            "_parent": {
               "type": "entity"
            },
            "_routing": {
               "required": true
            },
            "properties": {
               "FIRST_NAME": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "LAST_NAME": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here isn't related to multiple values, but your assumption that the `match`-query will match anything that starts with your input. It does not.

In the match-family of queries there's the [`match_phrase_prefix`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_match_phrase_prefix) that can be worth checking out. It is explained in a bit more detail here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/starts-with-phrase-matching/

There is also the [`prefix`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)-query, but note that it does not do any text analysis.

For a general introduction to text analysis, I can recommend these two articles:

- https://www.found.no/foundation/text-analysis-part-1/
- https://www.found.no/foundation/text-analysis-part-2/